# nHibernate many to many not getting list of child objects on retrieved object

Tags: nhibernate, many-to-many

```
        // load the client and any many to one relationships
        var clientRootQuery = session.QueryOver(() => clientAlias);
        clientRootQuery.Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Person, () => personAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => personAlias.SexType, () => sexTypeAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => personAlias.EyeColorType, () => eyeColorTypeAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Organization, () => organizationAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.ClientStatusType, () => clientStatusTypeAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Notes, () => noteAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => noteAlias.Comments, () => commentAlias)
        .Where(() => clientAlias.Id == clientId)
        .Future<Client>();

        // load the note collection into the nhibernate session 
        // todo ******************** this doesn't work.  nhibernate is still firing off queries in the adapter fill method rather than using the values pulled here.
        var notes = session.QueryOver(() => clientAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Notes, () => noteAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => noteAlias.Comments, () => commentAlias)
        .Where(() => clientAlias.Id == clientId)
        .Future<Client>();

return clientRootQuery.Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

This does not return many addresses on the client object nor does it return many notes. This should work. There is a client with many notes and many addresses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clientRootQuery = session.QueryOver(() => clientAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Person, () => personAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => personAlias.SexType, () => sexTypeAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => personAlias.EyeColorType, () => eyeColorTypeAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Organization, () => organizationAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.ClientStatusType, () => clientStatusTypeAlias)
        .Where(() => clientAlias.Id == clientId)
        .Future();

 var notes = session.QueryOver(() => clientAlias)
        .Left.JoinAlias(() => clientAlias.Notes, () => noteAlias)
        .Where(() => noteAlias.Client.Id == clientId)
        .Future();

var list = clientRootQuery.ToList();
        return list.FirstOrDefault();
```

It needs to be a left join.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why clientAddresses are not initialized is because you set a filter on them so NHibernate assumes that not all clientAddresses are loaded to fully initialize the collection.